# How do I build a multiple project solution in Visual Studio without dependencies between the binaries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Pro to build a solution that contains two projects. Project A contains most of my source code, while Project B is intended to run independently, but must use some of the source code contained in Project A.

Under the current configuration, Project A is contained as a reference within Project B. I'd like to be able to build and maintain versions of each project independently, but it appears that when I build the entire solution, ProjectB.exe cannot run without ProjectA.exe in the same local directory. I would think and hope that when the .exe binaries are compiled that all of their dependencies are packaged within each, but that appears not to be the case. In fact, any attempt to run ProjectB.exe while ProjectA.exe is not present results in a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

Is there a way to build a version ProjectB.exe that runs independently and avoids code duplication?

Comment: Create another project (let's say ProjectC), compile it as library (DLL) and put there all the shared code. Both ProjectA and ProjectB will have a reference to it (so you'll deploy ProjectA+ProjectC and ProjectB+ProjectC). No duplication. You can even share the same source files between two projects but hey...it's a dirty useless "trick".

Comment: By your very definition, B is dependent on A.  It must have a reference to A, either because A is compiled in the same solution, or to the A.DLL, but not part of the same solution.   What are you actually asking?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone -- especially Adriano. It's working like a charm now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you want common code, the best solution is to break out the common classes into a third assembly to serve as a library. (As per Adriano's suggestion.) The other option he hints at is to use the "as link" option when using the "add existing file" to the second project.

If you don't know where it is, use the "Add existing file" option, then in the dialog box to select the file, the "Add" button has a drop-down selection where you can select "As Linked File" (or something to that effect.)

This allows you to compile the same classes into multiple projects. But keep in mind that the namespacing for the linked file cannot be changed for the second project. If the namespace was "ProjectA.Domain", this is how you need to access it in Project B. This was a useful trick for Silverlight projects back before the multi-platform assemblies were introduced.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid or the dependency on A, you will have to extract the common logic into another project (let's call it C), as Adriano suggested in a comment.

If you need even looser bond between the projects, you can reference A (or C) not as a project, but as a built assembly (.dll file) and check `Specific Version` reference property to `True`. Additionally, if your project/codebase structure is more complex, check more assembly sharing options **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520063/share-common-codes-between-multiple-projects)**.

Comment: Are you sure embed interop types will do this? I though this was only for specially designed COM interop types and not for general assemblies.

Comment: It was. You may be right that it would bring more trouble than benefit to get the job done. Basically it should do the same as point 2 in your answer. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. The common option: Separate the common code into a third class library (DLL) project. And have both ProjectA and ProjectB dependent on it. The downside is that now in order to run the projects you need two files (the main exe and the dll.) This method is how most software is developed: a single executable and a bunch of DLLs.
2. The correct option: Separate the common code into a third project and modify the project files to create executables that contain both assemblies (similar to statically linked libraries in unmanaged code.) The downside is that Visual Studio does not support this out of the box and you need to modify the project files which are actually MS-Build definition files to do this.
3. The ugly option: Create shortcuts for the common files in ProjectA in ProjectB. This is the same as copying the common code to the other project, but you're still left with one source file. The downside is that you have to do this for every file and maintain the same structure in both projects. This is an ugly, if viable, option. Choose one of the others.